# https to http redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have searched everywhere and still can't find any answers.

I'm trying to redirect eg: https://www.domain.com to http://www.domain.com

Currently I have a `.htaccess` file which includes:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I keep receiving the following error:

```
An error occurred during a connection to www.domain.com.
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)...
```

Do I need to add anything to my vhost file for VirtualHost *:443? for domain.com - Apologies, quite new to this. Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could be many things, but to help you narrow it, usually SSL errors appears *before* it even reach htaccess.  Browser answers regarding SSL are provided before htaccess instructions (I think).  This site may help you http://www.errorhelp.com/search/details/69648/ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

Answer (score 4):

You need to have fully working https vhost. Please paste here what you have in your vhost.

```
<VirtualHost IP:443>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www.domain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/www.domain.key

    ReWriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

If you have the same vhost for http and https things can get messy. Btw your cert must have CNAME for `www.domain.com` or if you have wildcard `*.domain.com`. And one more thing, you don't need any `RewriteCond` here because you rewrite every https request.